# Running Mocha multiple times with the same data produces different results

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have been noticing. With no discernible pattern, that sometimes I run my mocha tests and get a failed assertion. then I run it again immediately. Without making any changes and the assertions all pass. Is there something that I'm doing wrong. Is there test data that is cached?

I, unfortunately don't know what to post, since I can't seem to pin this down to any one thing but here is one function I've seen it happen to

mysqltest.js

```
describe('get_tablet_station_name', function() {
        it ('isSuccessful', function() {
            mysqlDao.init();

            var callback = sinon.spy();

            mysqlDao.get_tablet_station_name(state.TABLET_NAME, function(err, result) {
                assert(err == undefined) 
            });
        });

        it ('isUnsuccessful', function() {
            mysqlDao.init();

            var callback = sinon.spy();

            mysqlDao.get_tablet_station_name("'''%\0", function(err, result) {
                assert(err != undefined);
            });
        });
    });
```

When the assertions fail it is

```
assert(err != undefined);
```

err is returning null despite the bad SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should share the error you are getting when test case is getting failed.

But from you code and problem described, I can guess that your mysql calls must be taking time greater than the default timeout of mocha test cases. And while running your test case for the second time mysql must be returning data from cache hence preventing timeout.

To debug try increasing the default timeout of your test case, and for that use inside you describe call ->

```
describe('get_tablet_station_name', function() {
this.timeout(10000);
......//rest of the code
```

Please note this could not be the solution,please provide why assertion is getting failed if above mentioned thing do not work.